# <canvas> crossbrowser - IE

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, jcanvas

How to make a working crossbrowser script with jCanvas

- In IE8 the canvas is not appended..
- In FF and Chrome the drawn frame isn't positioned at the right coords? The starting point is outside the viewport?!

## fsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4GSXC/

## code:

```
<!--[if IE]><script src="http://secure.dynaccount.com/js/jquery/excanvas.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="http://secure.dynaccount.com/js/jquery/jcanvas.5.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            
        function Canvas_overview(){
            var _this = this;
            
            this.width = 900;
            this.height = 360;
            
            this.frm_x = 80;
            this.frm_y = 30;
            this.frm_width = 800;
            this.frm_height = 280;
            
            this.cnstr = function(elm){
                var canvas = $('<canvas width="'+this.width+'" height="'+this.height+'" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>').appendTo(elm)
                    .drawRect({
                        strokeStyle: '#969696',
                        strokeWidth: 1,
                        x: this.frm_x,
                        y: this.frm_y,
                        width: this.frm_width,
                        height: this.frm_height
                    });
            };
        }
            
        var Canvas = new Canvas_overview();
        Canvas.cnstr($('body'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since excanvas doesn't support everything, I actually recommend using [FlashCanvas](http://flashcanvas.net/). It seems more likely to work than excanvas (since excanvas never worked for me).

In regards to the "wrong" coordinates, jCanvas considers (x, y) coordinates at the center of a shape by default (rather than the top-left corner). You can easily override this behavior by setting the fromCenter property to false (in your object).

Hope that helps.

-Caleb